# d3.js: Deletion / Navigation to child Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I wondered what is the best way to also delete the children A and B by selecting D and clicking Delete Button:

`d3.select("#deleteBtn").on("click", function() {
    d3.select(".selected").remove();

    // how to delete children as well?
});`

Is there a easy d3 way to navigate to the children data except using a traversing / recursive function?
Perhaps someone can give me a hint.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefanf/tLBra/24/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data for the selected node to the pack layout again to get an array of all the nodes that are children of it. Then bind that array to the circles with a key function to match the nodes by name, and remove them. This will work as long as each node has a unique name. Here is my solution:

```
d3.select("#deleteBtn").on("click", function() {
    d3.select(".selected").each(function(data){
        var nodesToRemove = pack.nodes(data);
        vis.selectAll("circle")
          .data(nodesToRemove, function(d){
            return d.name;
          })
          .remove();
        vis.selectAll("text")
          .data(nodesToRemove, function(d){
            return d.name;
          })
          .remove();
    })  
});
```

Here is an updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JMStewart/qCykp/